# How to break a capture if a specific character is match in Regex

Tags: regex

Lets say I have :
`voyage/asie/emirats-arabes-unis/dubai/`

I want to check if there is only `/asie/emirats-arabes-unis/` but not `/dubai/`.

**Is there a way to say capture everything but stop capturing if `/` is met ?**

Actually I was using this `voyage\/(.+)\/(.+)\/` but obviously there is a problem in those specific case.

[Shared playground](https://regex101.com/r/mY3uY5/1)

Comment: It is the regex basics: `[^/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`. Look for *regex character classes*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then -> https://regex101.com/r/mY3uY5/2

Comment: Why `.+`? I wrote `[^/]+`, see [`voyage\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)` demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY3uY5/3)

Comment: Hoo I get it ! Perfect thank you :) !